# How do I make an external interrupt in c++ on arduino due (sam3x8e) using only the registers?

Tags: c++, arduino

I am trying to create NVIC interrupts on the Arduino due.  I need 4 external interrupts from push buttons and am having trouble using anything but the NVIC interrupts.  First, can I use PMC_PCER0 for all 4 interrupts?  Second, can I make multiple interrupts on the same port?  Do I enable all interrupts with just one call to NVIC(PIOB_IRQn)? Finally, are there better methods and registers for external interrupts on the Arduino due (sam3x8e).

```
void configure_ext_int_1(){
    PMC->PMC_PCER0 |= 1 << ID_PIOB;         // Enable Clock for PIOB -                                           needed for sampling falling edge
    PIOB->PIO_PER = PIO_PB27;             // Enable IO pin control
    PIOB->PIO_ODR = PIO_PB27;             
    PIOB->PIO_PUER = PIO_PB27;            // Enable pull-up
    PIOB->PIO_IFER = PIO_PB27;            /
    PIOB->PIO_DIFSR = PIO_PB27;           // Select Debouncing filter 
    PIOB->PIO_SCDR = 0x4FF;               // Set Debouncing clock divider
    PIOB->PIO_AIMER = PIO_PB27;          
    PIOB->PIO_ESR = PIO_PB27;             
    PIOB->PIO_FELLSR = PIO_PB27;          
   PIOB->PIO_IER = PIO_PB27;          
   NVIC_EnableIRQ(PIOB_IRQn);            
}
```

Comment: If programmed this way, I would have 3 more similar functions to create the 3 additional interrupts.

Answer (score 0):

I have elected to use the asf functions available for the SAM3X8E.  I am not sure if this will work on all 4 ports simultaneously.

```
 void enable_NVIC_interrupts(){
 // PORT A NVIC
 pmc_enable_periph_clk(ID_PIOA);
 pio_set_input(PIOA, PIO_PA29, PIO_PULLUP;
 pio_handler_set(PIOA, ID_PIOC, PIO_PA29, PIO_IT_EDGE, int_RINGMODULATOR);
 pio_enable_interrupt(PIOA, PIO_PA29);
 NVIC_EnableIRQ(PIOA_IRQn);

 // PORT B NVIC
 pmc_enable_periph_clk(ID_PIOB);
 pio_set_input(PIOB, PIO_PB25, PIO_PULLUP;
 pio_handler_set(PIOB, ID_PIOB, PIO_PB25, PIO_IT_EDGE, int_TREMOLO);
 pio_enable_interrupt(PIOB, PIO_PB25);
 NVIC_EnableIRQ(PIOB_IRQn);

 // PORT C NVIC
 pmc_enable_periph_clk(ID_PIOC);
 pio_set_input(PIOC, PIO_PC22, PIO_PULLUP;
 pio_handler_set(PIOC, ID_PIOC, PIO_PC22, PIO_IT_EDGE, int_DISTORTION);
 pio_enable_interrupt(PIOC, PIO_PC22);
 NVIC_EnableIRQ(PIOC_IRQn);

 // PORT D NVIC
 pmc_enable_periph_clk(ID_PIOD);
 pio_set_input(PIOD, PIO_PD7, PIO_PULLUP;
 pio_handler_set(PIOD, ID_PIOD, PIO_PD7, PIO_IT_EDGE, int_REVERB);
 pio_enable_interrupt(PIOD, PIO_PD7);
 NVIC_EnableIRQ(PIOD_IRQn);
```